# Custom DropDownList Server Control Losing Items on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom server control inheriting from DropDownList. On postback, the items are lost. It looks something like this:

```
public class MyClientSelectList : DropDownList
{       
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        // design mode hack to let visual studio display in design mode
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select an item..."));
                // add more items from db
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked EnablePostBack = true. I select a selected value in the page load of my page which is hosting this custom server control.

Why are the items lost on postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnableViewState is already True by default, so mshsayem's solution will not work.
There're 2 way to do that, a standard way is to override SaveControlState and LoadControlState Method
Refer to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Another way is, in the Init, reload list items from database no matter postback or not, then retrieve the selected value from post data and set it back to dropdownlist